# Laravel : Call to undefined relationship [App\ActCategorie] on model [App\Actualite]

Tags: laravel

## Category Model :

```php
    public function Actualites() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Actualite','categorie_id');    
    }
```

## Actualite Model :

```php
    public function ActCategorie() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\ActCategorie');    
    }
```

## Controller

```php
     public function showAll(){
        $act = Actualite::with(ActCategorie::class)->get();
        return view('Admin.showAllActualite',['actualites' => $act]);
    }
```

## View :

```php
{{ $act->ActCategorie->name }}
```

Comment: What is the error?

Answer (score 0):

Replace the code with the following belong

```
public function showAll(){
    $act = Actualite::with('ActCategorie')->get();
    return view('Admin.showAllActualite',['actualites' => $act]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're [eager-loading a relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading), you'll use the name of the method referring to the relationship, not the name of the related class itself:

```
public function showAll()
{
    $act = Actualite::with('ActCategorie')->get();

    return view('Admin.showAllActualite',['actualites' => $act]);
}
```